# How to fill a transparent area of an SVG?

Tags: svg

I created this SVG by converting it from a transparent PNG. I want to use it but I need to fill in the inside part, the ‘i’ with a color. 
Right now it’s transparent.

Is there a way to do that? Fill it with a color?

I have it here on CodePen.

https://codepen.io/randometc/pen/Pdbzdd

```
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 
400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ><g id="svgg"><path 
id="path0" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750         
18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 
271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 
307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 
18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 
C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 
146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 
83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 
175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 
231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 
278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 
287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 
283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 
295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 
302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 
280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 
195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 
183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 
184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 
171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " 
stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path 
id="path1" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 
18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 
271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 
307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 
18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 
C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 
146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path2" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path3" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path4" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a filled circle of the approximate size at the beginning.

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ><g id="svgg"><circle fill="blue" cx="200" cy="200" r="150"/><path id="path0" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path1" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path2" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path3" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path id="path4" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fill-rule="evenodd"`creates a hole in your path. You can simply put a "name your color" rectangle behind.
Also: you have the same path repeated so I've deleted the extra paths.

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  

  <g id="svgg">
    
    <rect fill="red" x="100" y="65" width="200" height = "250" />

    <path id="test" d="M187.375 18.164 C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164 M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823 M193.036 161.512 C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none"  fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g>
    
</svg>
```

Yet another way of doing it is splitting your path by "M" ( move to ) like this:

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  

  <g id="svgg">
  <path id="test" d="M187.375 18.164 
                       C 186.825 18.208,184.744 18.363,182.750 18.509 
                       C 104.064 24.247,37.115 83.506,21.509 161.230 
                       C -0.548 271.072,81.512 373.504,193.500 375.917 
                       C 286.453 377.921,365.771 307.642,375.113 215.000 
                       C 385.770 109.308,302.472 17.520,196.375 18.044 
                       C 191.975 18.066,187.925 18.120,187.375 18.164" />
                       
    <g id="i" fill="red"> 
    <!-- i dot -->
    <path d="M220.301 87.823 C 239.254 92.844,246.530 115.141,233.695 128.871 
                       C 216.903 146.835,185.788 136.394,185.658 112.750 
                       C 185.564 95.558,202.770 83.178,220.301 87.823" /> 
    <-- i body -->                  
    <path d="M193.036 161.512 
                       C 212.655 163.497,223.008 175.187,221.761 193.949 
                       C 221.056 204.551,221.049 204.580,213.357 231.750 
                       C 204.889 261.658,204.164 264.895,204.139 272.875 
                       C 204.120 278.976,204.888 281.479,207.498 283.826 
                       C 212.127 287.987,225.059 287.887,235.589 283.608 
                       C 236.411 283.274,237.102 283.029,237.124 283.063 
                       C 237.146 283.097,236.496 285.864,235.679 289.212 
                       L 234.195 295.299 233.285 295.682 
                       C 231.001 296.645,217.243 301.823,213.875 302.988 
                       C 191.395 310.761,168.677 305.477,160.982 290.686 
                       C 155.575 280.294,156.513 271.104,166.615 235.500 
                       C 176.322 201.288,177.339 195.507,174.991 187.905 
                       C 172.679 180.420,161.822 178.620,147.485 183.345 
                       C 145.225 184.090,143.343 184.669,143.303 184.632 
                       C 143.264 184.595,143.920 181.815,144.760 178.454 
                       L 146.289 172.343 147.332 171.943 
                       C 172.432 162.300,181.153 160.310,193.036 161.512 " stroke="none"></path></g></g>
    
</svg>
```